# Do Google SEO Content Keywords matter and should I remove sidebar content?-

Tags: magento, seo, duplicates, keyword

I run a Magento based store website.

At the side of every product page we have delivery information.

Because of this, Google Webmaster tools picks up words such as 'delivery' 'orders' 'returns' as significant keywords - rather than more relevant 'industry specific' keywords.

Does it matter that he gives 'delivery' a higher significant rating?

Should I remove the delivery info from the side of each page?

Or is there a way to disavow keywords to tell Google that 'delivery' isn't relevant?

Or maybe turn the text info at the side into a graphic instead?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before SEO, you should always consider what is best for your user. If displaying shipping information in the sidebar is going to enhance the user's experience, leave it. If the information could be put on a page and a link can be added the sidebar, do that.

Having said that, I wouldn't worry about it. Unless you're trying to rank for the keywords 'return' or 'delivery', you're not likely to notice any sort of algorithm penalty that comes from having the words appear all over the website.

Furthermore, a keyword stuffing penalty is applied to each page individually. You should be careful with stuffing your keywords in tags on the side, as it will increase the keyword density.